# How to change View in WebPart from JS?

Tags: javascript, web-part, document-library, list-view

I have a simple document library web part added to my SharePoint `aspx` page.

I'm wondering if I can change the **View** inside a **Document Library WebPart** from **JavaScript** dynamically?

**For Example:**

```
http://SiteURL?viewName=Test
```

Here `Test` is my current **View**

And the Document Library is having default `All Documents` **View**. I want that the document library web part should change the **View** from `All Documents` to `Test` **View**.

Is something like this possible using JavaScript?

Comment: Please explain which can of page and add an image if you can.

Comment: The given edit for the question is what one would expect the requirement to be. However, the initial question could be altered to different requirements, which is why I'd hope the OP @kolek to confirm whether the question is now addressing the original requirement.

Comment: yes it still meets the requirements

Comment: Do you want to change the view to **Test** permanently? Or it should be changed according to query string?

Comment: It should change according to query string

Comment: It's not possible using **JS**, unfortunately!

Answer (score 2):

ListView WebPart's added on a page, its source view cannnot be changed dynamically using client side code ( JavaScript ).

However, here are work arounds:

## Method #1

1. Insert an IFrame on your page and set the source to View page URL with passing URL parameter `IsDlg=1`. Example: `AllItems.aspx?IsDlg=1`
2. Use JavaScript to update IFrame source URL

## Method # 2

You can pass filter parameters to your page.

`YourPage.aspx?FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=SomeValue`

You can also extend it to pass more paraters like this:
`YourPage.aspx?FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=SomeValue&FilterField2=OtherField&FilterValue2=OtherValue`

So, using JavaScript you need to reload page with required URL parameters.

> The downside of this solution is that filter applies to all ListView
>   WebParts on that page.
>   [image]